# Subsetting Factors in R

Tags: r, subset, factors

```
s <- split (x, x$factor)
s[[1]]
```

So I would like to be able to use that subset of the factors with `lapply`. Below is a mock code simulated what I was trying to do.

```
meanfunction <-lapply(s[[1]],function(x) colMeans(x[, c("col1","col2")]))
```

But it doesn't work.  So I though I would be smart and try to trick R and bind a new variable `t<-s[[1]]` and then use that in the function, but alas it did not work either. Either approach I get the same error message.

```
Error in x[, c("col1", "col2")] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

But the code works just fine when evaluated as a whole. Any thoughts? Thanks.

Edit : 
x is a data.frame with 4 columns
Character, numeric, numeric, factor

Comment: `s[[1]]` is a data frame, so calling `lapply` on it runs `colMeans` on each column, which would not work

Comment: @RichardScriven Even when I specify the columns?  Is there any work around for that?

Comment: I presume you're talking about the two middle columns, so `colMeans(x[2:3], na.rm = TRUE)` would work on a single data frame.  No `lapply` needed for that

Comment: @RichardScriven And then going back to my example I would have to use my new variable, `t<-s[[1]]`?  Doing this did get the outcome that I desired, thank you, but I am working on a longer code and in the long run I do need to use`lapply`

Comment: Okay, so if you have a list `lst` full of data frames, you can do `lapply(lst, function(x) colMeans(x[2:3], na.rm = TRUE))` and that should work.  But your `t` is a single data frame, and that's why it's not working.  A data frame is itself a list, so `lapply` on a single data frame iterates over the columns

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, that helps. Will have to work on it a little.

Answer (score 1):

`dplyr` is a great choice for this kind of job, supposing I understood your goal correctly. Here is an example:

```
library(dplyr)
x = tbl_df(data.frame(factor = factor(c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 4))), value = 1:7))
group_by(x, factor) %>% summarise(mean = mean(value))
```

You can find more about `dplyr` [here](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html).

Comment: You can use `summarise_each` for more than 1 column.  From the OP's post, I guess there are multiple columns.